# Extracting % occurrences in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have following output in str format

```
    Port      Name        Intvl   In Mbps      %  In Kpps  Out Mbps      % Out Kpps
    Et7/1                  5:00     338.2   3.4%       31       0.0   12.3%        121
```

I need to exact all percentage occurrences i.e *3.4* and *12.3*.
What is the most pythonic way to do the same

**find_all** with *%* just gives the index, is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=%)
```

with `re.findall` should do it for you.

```
print re.findall(r"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=%)",test_str)
```

EDIT:

if you want `float` values instead of `str` use

```
print map(ast.literal_eval,re.findall(r"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=%)",x))
```

We are using `\b` which is for word boundary.[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/14)

Comment: It gives ['4',3'] not [3.4, 12.3]